# Javascript logical operators and strings/numbers

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I can't understand how logical operators works. I know how it works with boolean values, but what about strings or numbers?

```
2 && 7
returns 7

"dog" && "cat"
returns "cat"
```

I see, that if number or strings doesn't have same value then second value is returned. But why? For what I can use it in "real world"?

Comment: Mozilla JavaScript Documentation for operators  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: @AurA to add link with text use `[text](link)` same as on github.

Answer (score 9):

If the left hand side is true, then it evaluates as the right hand side.

If the left hand side is not true, then it evaluates as the left hand side.

---

`false && true` evaluates as the LHS. So is `false`.

`false && false` evaluates as the LHS. So is `false`.

`true && false` evaluates as the RHS hand side. So is `false`.

`true && true` evaluates as the RHS. So is `true`.

`2 && 7` evaluates as the RHS. So is `7` (which is true).

`0 && 7` evaluates as the LHS. So is `0` (which is false).

`"cat" && "dog"` evaluates as the RHS hand side. So is `"dog"` (which is true).

---

`||` works in the same way, but returns the LHS if it is false.

---

> For what I can use it in "real world"?

The main way you can use it is to work out if *both* values are true. Which is the point of the operator.

(It also has uses as a shorthand `if` test and for determining which of two values to assign somewhere).

Comment: Perhaps a nice addition to your list would be `"" && "dog"`. Which evaluates to `""`.

Answer (score 5):

The `&&` operator does not return a boolean, it returns one of its operands. Because the operands are evaluated *as booleans* anyway. Since `2` is *truthy*, and `7` is *truthy*, returning `7` is the same as returning `true`, because the result is *truthy*. For `0 && 7`, it returns `0`, since that's *falsey*, which is the expected outcome.

In a boolean context this behaviour is identical to returning `true` or `false`, but it allows useful behaviours in other contexts. The most often encountered is:

```
foo = foo || 'bar';
```

If `||` (and `&&`) would return a boolean, you'd have to write this instead:

```
if (!foo) {
    foo = 'bar';
}
```

or:

```
foo = foo ? foo : 'bar';
```

Answer (score 0):

How logical operators work is well explained on MDN [Logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

> For what can i use it in "real world"?

You can use the || operator for sorting an array on multiple keys.

Example:

```
const myArray = [{ age: 25, name: 'Patrick' },
{ age: 22, name: 'Greta' },
{ age: 22, name: 'Fien' }];
myArray.sort((a, b) => (a.age - b.age) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
console.log('myArray=', JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

The sort-method normally (not in the example above) returns 1, 0 or -1, so perhaps the following can help to make it easier to understand.

```
console.log( 1 || 1); // 1
console.log( 1 || 0); // 1
console.log( 1 ||-1); // 1
console.log( 0 || 1); // 1
console.log( 0 || 0); // 0
console.log( 0 ||-1); //-1
console.log(-1 || 1); //-1
console.log(-1 || 0); //-1
console.log(-1 ||-1); //-1
```

Also the 'Short-circuit evaluation' of the || operator is beneficial.